# Pandora client with Web Interface?

Tags: software-recommendation, pandora

I am look for a Pandora client that I can install on a headless Ubuntu box I mainly use as a file server. It sits right next to my stereo system, and it would be nice if I could hook them together to listen to Pandora (which we right now with a laptop we plug in temporarily when we want to do it).

Are there any programs out there that could do this for me?

Answer (score 2):

I use Pandora from the terminal. This would be a great scenario for this setup. You can ssh to your headless box that is connected to your sound system and run Pandora from the CLI.

Install Pianobar and make sure your sound devices are setup for outputto the stereo.

Lifehacker has a good writeup:

http://m.lifehacker.com/5713551/pianobar-is-a-flash+free-pandora-player-inside-your-terminal

Simple interface too, you can browse your stations and everything...